# PostgreSQL: Illuminate\Database\QueryException: SQLSTATE[42703]: Undefined column: 7 ERROR: column "distance" does not exist. laravel

Tags: php, laravel, postgresql

I am working on a feature to find nearby cars (radius <10Km) based on latitude, longitude, and radius. But an error occurs when executing the query I created.
the code:

```
$nearby = Vehicle::with('users','vehicle_feature.feature');

//NEARBY
        if(request('latitude') && request('longitude')){
            $latitude = request('latitude');
            $longitude = request('longitude');
            $radius = request('radius') != null ? request('radius') : 10; // 10 km radius
            $nearby = $nearby
        ->selectRaw("*, (
            6371 * acos(
                cos(radians(?)) * cos(radians(parking_latitude)) * cos(radians(parking_longitude) -    radians(?)) 
               + sin(radians(?)) * sin(radians(parking_latitude))
            )
        ) AS distance", [$latitude, $longitude, $latitude])
        ->having('distance', '<=', $radius)
        ->whereIn('id', $result_rental_available)
        ->orderBy('distance')
        ->take(10)
        ->get();
            
        }
```

This is the error:

```
Illuminate\Database\QueryException: SQLSTATE[42703]: Undefined column: 7 ERROR:  column &quot;distance&quot; does not exist
LINE 6: ..., $47) and &quot;vehicles&quot;.&quot;deleted_at&quot; is null having &quot;distance&quot;...
                                                             ^ (SQL: select *, (
            6371 * acos(
                cos(radians(55.67209151)) * cos(radians(parking_latitude)) * cos(radians(parking_longitude) - radians(12.56362796))
                + sin(radians(55.67209151)) * sin(radians(parking_latitude))
            )
        ) AS distance from &quot;vehicles&quot; where &quot;user_id&quot; &lt;&gt; a21209ca-24b5-4ea0-a701-a676de20bef7 and &quot;id&quot; in (01e4418c-f839-4881-b887-e476684d2b7d, 03973a8f-7b72-4012-baf5-fd1dc0a0c2ca, 050cfad7-6b8a-4d69-a39b-9a3228b3ea5c, 0d2fb0a8-f9dc-4317-91fe-3b3a9cad4071, 11575b01-8656-4eb8-bb70-48b579bca247, 151b583d-fb86-43ca-8054-2352f06f2f86, 22ec2c31-00eb-432f-a7e9-ed39313cd865, 283c6794-f700-4fb7-99f1-e1ddc2ca2cb4, 313c9742-a6aa-4f88-8f9e-8dd71a8f113b, 361e8840-4621-45b9-8553-cc35945f1d55, 3b57dd17-0674-41f8-8b9c-9fdfeec9adea, 3f24fa60-3e06-45a0-b267-dbbc8f1d382f, 42987e4a-2a99-4607-8d39-325fbd4dcacc, 46d65af0-1c75-45d8-bd06-f3946f976a16, 4cc0a1a7-dc23-4697-a8b3-3ba5dd0c7be6, 5e1f74fd-4036-4bb6-84dc-8810b765c54b, 685025e0-cf80-42be-90a3-63ea582cb3d2, 7131688f-7d38-4430-8f6f-089b15a4f90b, 71ed0ff9-bea5-4fdb-91e8-859566251190, 75245e7e-b58a-4e75-9f16-6994210820d3, 84eb2a33-0487-432f-9d5a-7860afab2b01, 88e80f28-d409-4fd3-84ca-625143985385, 8d80c918-0a31-4d94-9a97-c857a9f3b9f0, 969b5a66-9c1c-4ea5-99fd-b63dba167d7e, 97c797c6-0f3f-4781-85a4-6840b387c751, 99056d58-d712-4487-b173-e8b7be6027aa, 9f85574c-a092-4931-9a95-102017539d39, a2fea1df-3661-42aa-b894-a2c05cdd7658, a705d5e6-dfd3-4456-a83f-9ef5cc239866, b5d12ceb-9ce8-4a0f-8370-90eff4c2b206, bc8d484a-8367-41ea-969c-02c2967a954e, bca7214d-6ccb-42d0-9b9d-2cc162169f5f, d490bd21-efe1-482c-b3a4-1a839071622e, e14e2e30-9f2e-4256-9481-9232f0ad5209, e9dabfad-3a14-4b70-83f9-77b2bd003954, ea6fa50e-03fc-4637-9a47-d65c93eb015d, ee216e12-75bd-446b-85ba-5df4d2dfe757, f2051397-8616-49f4-9d77-fd113d09d57c, f4685109-2335-487c-810c-bf03974e8e3d, f69b00e6-2348-4966-b57f-e06accd21960, fbc11056-ff05-4f48-959d-65529cc1343b, fc3cbb24-6932-4fd6-9afb-c0db70bb847e, fe6df2db-0223-4425-8783-e6b1cab8085e) and &quot;vehicles&quot;.&quot;deleted_at&quot; is null having &quot;distance&quot; &lt;= 10 order by &quot;distance&quot; asc limit 10)
```

I don't know where the query error is. But when the having() and orderBy() parts are removed, the query runs normally. i am using postgreSQL.

Comment: You want `whereIn`, not `having`.  `having` is only used with grouping and aggregate functions.

Comment: The issue has been resolved. PostgreSQL cannot use the Haversine formula to calculate distances; instead, it uses the built-in 'earth_distance' function.

Comment: of course Postgres can use whatever you want to compute a column named "distance", including the Haversine formula or even `1+1`.... but if you write an error, PG will rightfully tell you so. Try `select 1 as test where test =>1;` and see that the same error message will be printed out. The issue here is that you can't refer to the alias of the computed column. Either rewrite the same expression in the `where` clause, or wrap it in an inner query: `select * from (select 1 as test) as sub where test >= 1;`